# Crash when restarting a scene

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, dealloc, sprite-sheet

So, here is my scene problem: I start from a Menu Scene, then go into the InGame Scene, and when the character is dead, I go to the Menu Scene again, all this using:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[MainMenu scene]];
```

and

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[InGame scene]];
```

After losing the game, and trying to go back to the game, my SpriteSheet crashes with the error :

```
'CCSprite is not using the same texture id'
```

Here is how I init the animation :

```
- (void) initSprite:(NSString *)plist andTexture:(NSString *)texture_ {

[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:plist];

spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:texture_];

NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i=1; i<=12; i++) {
    [walkAnimFrames addObject:
     [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",i]]];
}

CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.05f];

texture = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"1.png"];
walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim]];
[texture runAction:walkAction];

texture.position = position;
texture.tag = HeroType;
[spriteSheet addChild:texture];

[self addChild:spriteSheet];
}
```

The crash occurs when I add the texture to the spriteSheet:

```
[spriteSheet addChild:texture];
```

I believe the problem comes from the deallocation of the texture..

I don't use ARC.

Comment: Your use of sprite sheets here is superfluous. For each sprite that you create with initSprite, you create a sprite batch node for that one sprite. With or without the batch node you end up with one draw call per sprite. Batches don't speed up animations, they speed up rendering multiple sprites using the same texture so that you can display 10 or hundreds of the same sprites in a single draw call.

Comment: I understand, I was using it to draw an animation of a character running. I have a sprite sheet of 12 sprites (http://oi42.tinypic.com/2s6oe3n.jpg) , what would be the best way to do that in your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a "1.png" in the cache that corresponds to another animation that was created before quit-restart sequence. Maybe you want to purge the sprite frame cache (and possibly a whole lot of other things) prior to restarting.

I completely avoid "1.png" through 'NNNN.png' since in all likelihood all your animations will have them. Instead i use things like :

walk_classKey_upNNNN.png   {up,down,left,right,idle,jump ... and any other map stance i need)
fight_classKey_strikeNNNN.png  {strike,hurt,dead ... for example)

classKey is {fighter,rogue, ... etc ... whichever unique soldier type I have)

and i name my plists/textures the same

walk_fighter_up-hd.plist (using texture packer, the plist embeds the texture name).
fight_rogue_cheapShot-hd.plist  (cheapShot is one of my rogue's skill in my current game).

Comment: It was the cache, thank you. Just added `[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFrames];` and it works.

What does NNNN.png correspond to?

Comment: frames named 1.png, 2.png, 3.png ... NNN.png.